# Send HTTP request and receive HTTP response using javascript

Tags: javascript, http, request, response

I want to send HTTP request like a simple request for "http://google.com/" and then print the HTTP response headers on screen. How can it be done?
I want the base code so that I can use it to send more complex GET and POST requests.

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
function sendgetreq()
{
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', "https://www.google.com/search?q=asd", true);
    req.send(null);
    var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
    //document.write("Headers are:"+headers);
    alert(headers);
}
</script>
<INPUT TYPE=BUTTON OnClick="sendgetreq();" VALUE="Send Request">

</body>
</html>
```

This shows me an empty popup box.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_first

Comment: Thanks @Ajeet for the quick reply. I had tried both but they didn't work for me. Check out the code I have posted now.

Comment: The link i posted will get you headers for your own domain only as cross domain restrictions will apply for external domains.

Comment: @Ajeet: But I want to send a GET request to google.com and fetch the response header.

Comment: that is restricted by same origin policy .http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

Answer (score 0):

You can't use XMLHttpRequest cross domain unless requested server explicitly allow it and google.com doesn't explicitly allow it.
However you may disable the web security feature of your browser, and then your same code will start working.